# É permitido divulgar os links de nossas respostas?

Tags: debate, hyperlinks, divulgação

É permitido aos usuários promoverem em outros sites os links de suas respostas do StackOverflow?

Por exemplo, suponhamos que um usuário tenha um site sobre JavaScript, e que ele respondeu aqui no StackOverflow a uma pergunta sobre JavaScript. Caso ele publique um artigo a respeito do mesmo assunto abordado na pergunta e resposta, seria permitido que tal usuário coloque links no seu site redirecionando para sua resposta?

Comment: Eu acho que não somente é permitido como é estimulado. A ideia é justamente que o SOPT se torne um centro de conhecimento. Se você trouxer alguém a partir de um link no seu blog, talvez essa pessoa se torne um membro de valor para a comunidade e ai todo mundo ganha. :)

Comment: Já está tudo dito/respondido. Quando partilhares a pergunta lembra-te de usar o link "compartilhar" e não o do URL. Só assim o [pt.so] sabes quem partilhou o link e lhe dá crédito devido.

Comment: Relacionado: [Posso postar respostas do SO no meu blog?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2286/3117)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Não só permitido como é estimulado, como disse o @Luiz Vieira. Inclusive há 3 medalhas para esta finalidade:

- <kbd>Anunciador</kbd>  25 endereços IP diferente acessaram um link que você compartilhou
- <kbd>Incentivador</kbd>  300 endereços IP diferente acessaram um link que você compartilhou
- <kbd>Jornalista</kbd>  1000 endereços IP diferente acessaram um link que você compartilhou

Comment: Eu sempre achei que essas medalhas eram para links postados no SO que as pessoas seguiram (clicaram no link aqui dentro). Talvez seja útil alterar a descrição... Ou sou eu quem entendi errado.

Comment: Tem uma questão sobre elas, vou procurar e coloco o link.

Comment: Mais tarde vou olhar direito também, talvez propor uma alteração da descrição das medalhas... Inclusive indicando a questão do compartilhar link... Mas talvez seja um item de baixa prioridade...

Comment: O medalha difícil de conseguir :( - Tenho que aprender as estratégias de vocês.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, a medalha *Anunciador* foi concedida 14 vezes, somente ela saiu até agora.

Comment: @PapaCharlie perdão, é que as vezes acesso o SOen - confusão minha :)

Answer (score 10):

Pra complementar a resposta do [@PapaCharlie](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4169/3635) vou falar sobre a licença que é mantido o conteúdo dos sites do StackExchange:

Os sites usam para o conteúdo postado, a licença *Creative Commons 3.0* que diz:

> Você é livre para:
>
> - Compartilhar — Copiar e redistribuir o material em qualquer meio de comunicação e formato.
> - Adaptar — Misturar, transformar e criar usando o material para qualquer proposito, inclusive comercial.

Quem licencia não pode revogar essas liberdades desde que você siga os termos da licença.

Detalhes dos termos que deve seguir: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Answer (score 2):

Links para o SO são ótimos. Lembrar que o google baseia a ranking no número de links para o site.

Independente, inclusive, da autoria (se a resposta é sua ou não).

Comment: Mais delicado é postar aqui links para conteúdo externo de sua autoria/em site ou blog pessoal... Isso sim deve ser feito com cuidado pois pode ser considerado auto-promoção. Mas não é o caso que foi perguntado.